# Django - Add an extra field to an inline form in admin interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-admin

Suppose I have the following in `admin.py`:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ImageInline, ]
```

How do I add an extra field to `ImageInline` that is not a field in `Image` model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you would do it with a normal ModelAdmin. The InlineModelAdmin can accept a form attribute, [it's mentioned in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form). So create a custom form, add the extra fields you want and in your Inline:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Image
   form = MyCustomForm
```

Comment: Is it possible for `MyCustomForm` to have the initial fields that would appear without adding the `form` attribute? As in, I would just append to it instead of rewriting the fields. Something in the nature of `super`.

Comment: Ok I got this one with `ModelForm` and `class Meta: model = Image`

Answer (score 2):

8 years after, the accepted answer will not work.

For example to render custom form fields in `MyInlineForm` in the following setup in `Django-2.2.3`:

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyInlineModel
    form = MyInlineForm

@admin.register(MyModelAdmin)
class MyModelAdmin(admn.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyInlineAdmin,)
```

Inspired from [@santhoshnsscoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31787817/2996101), this can be achieved by overriding `ModelFormMetaclass.__new__`:

**Solution 1:**

```
from django.forms.models import ModelFormMetaclass


class MyModelFormMetaclass(ModelFormMetaclass):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for field in ['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3']:
            attrs[field] = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class MyInlinelForm(forms.ModelForm, metaclass=MyModelFormMetaclass):
    class Meta:
        model = MyInlineModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Reviewing the relevant code, [`ModelFormMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/68cc954ffba7fff0b672adf75a04f1d488efa652/django/forms/models.py#L206) inherits from [`DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/68cc954ffba7fff0b672adf75a04f1d488efa652/django/forms/forms.py#L25) where `attrs` are passed to `declared_fields` of the form:

```
for key, value in list(attrs.items()):
    if isinstance(value, Field):
        current_fields.append((key, value))
        attrs.pop(key)
attrs['declared_fields'] = OrderedDict(current_fields)
```

Based on this observation, and following the relevant docs of [`ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines)
I tried to enrich the `declared_fields` using that method of `ModelAdmin` and it also worked:

**Solution 2:**

```
class MyInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyInlineModel
        fields = '__all__'

class MyInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyInlineModel
    form = MyInlineForm

@admin.register(MyModelAdmin)
class MyModelAdmin(admn.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyInlineAdmin,)

def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
    for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
        if isinstance(inline, MyInlineAdmn):
            for field in ['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3']:
                inline.form.declared_fields[field] = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

        yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ReactionInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = Reaction

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

        if db_field.name == "reaction":

            from fb_post.constants.enums import Reactions
            select_choices = [('None', None)] + Reactions.get_list_of_tuples()

            kwargs['widget'] = forms.Select(choices=select_choices) # the other case for ModelAdmin "kwargs['widget'].choices = select_choices" this would work

        return super(ReactionInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

For adding dropdown menu feature for an enum field of app model(say Reaction) on admin panel, for class extending StackedInline or TabularInline class; this would work. The solution for the other case, class extending ModelAdmin is also given in **comment**

Answer (score 0):

Create **"CustomImageForm" class** with **"extra_field"** and set it to **"ImageInline" class** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Image, ObjectAdmin

# Here
class CustomImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField()
    
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    form = CustomImageForm # Here

@admin.register(ObjectAdmin)
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInline,]
```