# Add dynamic field to django admin model form

Tags: python, django

I need to add the field with link to the model view on my site to the django admin view.
When I add field name to the `list_display` and define method for rendering this url:

```
class SetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['many other fields', 'show_set_url']

    def show_set_url(self, obj):
            return '<a href="#">Set</a>' # render depends on other fields
```

It shows in Sets list in django admin, but not in model form.
How can I fix this and add link to the Sets Form in django admin?

I've tried also to create custom form for this model:

```
from core.models import Set
from django import forms

class SetAdminForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Set

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'] = forms.IntegerField(label=u"Link")
```

But there is now visible effect in form.

Comment: No, now I get KeyError: "Key u'show_set_url' not found in Form"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying by overriding `ModelAdmin` but you also need to override `ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007095/dynamic-fields-in-django-admin) answer might help you out. The OP in the link has a similar problem as well.

**Edit:** If you don't want an editable field you can try overriding `ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields`. Also check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for more attributes to override.

Comment: Yep, something like this. But I get as an editable field, and I need it as clickable link. How can I render it like a link?

Comment: Overriding ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields should do it. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for the full list of overridable attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can create dynamic fields and fieldset using the form meta class. Sample code is given below. Add the loop logic as per you requirements.

```
class CustomAdminFormMetaClass(ModelFormMetaclass):
    """
    Metaclass for custom admin form with dynamic field
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for field in myloop: #add logic to get the fields
            attrs[field] = forms.CharField(max_length=30) #add logic to the form field
        return super(CustomAdminFormMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class CustomAdminForm(six.with_metaclass(CustomAdminFormMetaClass, forms.ModelForm)):
    """
    Custom admin form
    """

    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = "__all__" 


class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Custom admin 
    """

    fieldsets = None
    form = CustomAdminForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Different fieldset for the admin form
        """
        self.fieldsets = self.dynamic_fieldset(). #add logic to add the dynamic fieldset with fields
        return super(CustomAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def dynamic_fieldset(self):
        """
        get the dynamic field sets
        """
        fieldsets = []
        for group in get_field_set_groups: #logic to get the field set group
            fields = []
            for field in get_group_fields: #logic to get the group fields
                fields.append(field)

            fieldset_values = {"fields": tuple(fields), "classes": ['collapse']}
            fieldsets.append((group, fieldset_values))

        fieldsets = tuple(fieldsets)

        return fieldsets
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, I changed a little bit, just needed to override the get_readonly_fields method, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add it to the `readonly_fields` list.

```
class SetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['many other fields', 'show_set_url']
    readonly_fields = ['show_set_url']

    def show_set_url(self, obj):
            return '<a href="#">Set</a>' # render depends on other fields
```

[Relevant documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with all of these answers in Django 1.9 for inline models.

Here is a code snippet that accomplished dynamic fields for me.  In this example, I'm assuming you already have a modal called ProductVariant which contains a foreign key relationship to a model called Product:

```
class ProductVariantForm(forms.ModelForm):
  pass

class ProductVariantInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = ProductVariant
  extra = 0

  def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    types = ( (0, 'Dogs'), (1, 'Cats'))
        #Break this line appart to add your own dict of form fields.
        #Also a handy not is you have an instance of the parent object in obj
    ProductVariantInline.form = type( 'ProductVariantFormAlt', (ProductVariantForm, ), { 'fancy_select': forms.ChoiceField(label="Animals",choices=types)})
    formset = super( ProductVariantInline, self).get_formset( request, obj, **kwargs)
    return formset

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = (ProductVariantInline, )
```

My specific use case is ProductVariant has a many to many relationship that should only have limited selections based on business logic grouping of the entries.  Thus my need for custom dynamic fields in the inline.